# Asymptotic Analysis of Cubed Root

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, roots

According to one of my textbooks, $\sqrt{n}$ is of higher order than $(\log{n})^2$.  When I compare $\sqrt[3]{n}$ and $(\log{n})^3$ in my graphing calculator, though, it appears that $(\log{n})^3$ is of higher order than $\sqrt[3]{n}$.  Is there a general conclusion I can draw about $\sqrt[k]{n}$ and $(\log{n})^k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (which one increases faster asymptotically)?

Comment: for your dsegree 3 thing,  take $n \approx 2.543803489 \cdot 10^{13}.$  Then $\log_e n \approx 30.8672, $   and $\left(\log_e n  \right)^3 \approx 29409.965  \; . \; \;  $   And $  \sqrt[3] n  \approx  29409.965 $   After that the log number is smaller.

Comment: Nice @WillJagy thank you!  If you put your comment in an answer I'll accept and upvote so you get some rep for your trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, with more accuracy, the place where your two degree 3 items are equal   is a real number between the consecutive integers
$$  25438034785804    \; \; \; , \; \; \;  25438034785805   $$
for the larger, we have $\log_e n  \approx 30.867266602430960527909691312812151398  $   so that $(\log_e n )^3 \approx29409.965764690120213895623606447861451 $  And $ \sqrt[3] n \approx  29409.965764690231895945701392803872488  $

Comment: Did you use software for this analysis?  If so, which software did you use?

Comment: @user2661923   pari-gp. I kept $n$  and integer, then did a binary search. Once I had two nearby integers (about 25 apart)  I placed $n$ as the lower integer and kept adding one.

Comment: Would you do it for $k=10$ ? (joke).

Comment: Do you concieve that I used Isabelle ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  also new one, never heard of    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabelle_(proof_assistant)   before. You are a funny guy.

Comment: I do note know if I am funny. This just means how old I am ! Cheers

Comment: I forgot to precise that Bordeaux was my *alma mater* . This explains that. Moreover  I saw *Isabelle* born and I was almost old in 1979. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using algebra, we have the explicit solution
$$n^{\frac{1}{k}}=\log ^k(n)$$
Let $n=e^x$ and raise to power $k$ to make
$$e^x=x^{k^2}\qquad \implies \qquad x=-k^2\,\, W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$
$$n=\exp\left(-k^2\,\, W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \right)$$ that you could round the way you want.

If you cannot use Lambert function, you can use the bounds given by Chatzigeorgiou in $2013$

$$-1-\sqrt{2u} -u <  W_{-1}\left(-e^{-u-1}\right)<-1-\sqrt{2u} -\frac 23u $$  Using
$u=2\log(k)-1 $ gives
$$\frac{1}{3} k^2 \left(4 \log (k)+3 \sqrt{4 \log (k)-2}+1\right)  < x <k^2 \left(2 \log (k)+\sqrt{4 \log (k)-2}\right)$$
Start with $x_0$ at the midpoint and make one iteration of Newton method o get
$$x_1=x_0-\frac{x_0 \left(x_0-k^2 \log (x_0)\right)}{x_0-k^2}$$

Trying for $k=3$ gives
$$30.1100 < x <33.7016\qquad \implies \qquad x_0=31.9058\qquad \implies \qquad x_1=30.8741$$ while the exact solution is $x=30.8673$.

Now, a binary search for $n$ will be quite fast.

Comment: good. Chatzigeorgiou   https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.04895.pdf   news to me

Answer (score 1):

Let $a(n)=n^{1/k}$, $b(n)= \log(n)^k$

Then, let $La(n) = \log a(n) = \frac{1}{k} \log n$, and $Lb(n)= k \log \log n$

Then, $La(n)$ is of higher order, and so is $a(n)$, for any $k$.